# python pandas how to multiply columns by other values in different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 DataFrames:

`df1` (original has about 3000 rows x 200 columns: 190 to add and multiply, rest has some other information):

```
           tag    A35    A37    A38
ITEM 
B1         SAS    8.0    3.0    1.0
B2         HTW    1.0    3.0    3.0
B3         ASD    0.0    8.0    0.0
B4         KLD    1.0   10.0    0.0
```

`df2` (in row have matching "prices" to columns in df1):

```
         day1      day2  
prices
A35           1       3
A37           2       2
A38           3       1
```

I'd like to add columns in `df1` with overall day1_price and day2_price with scheme:

```
df1.B1-day1_price = df1.B1_A35 * df2.A35_day1 + 
                    df1.B1_A37 * df2.A37_day1 + 
                    df1.B1_A38 * df2.A38_day1
```

So it should be for row1 day1: `(b1) = 8*1+3*2+1*3= 17`

```
           tag    A35    A37    A38    day1_price  day2_price
ITEM 
B1         SAS    8.0    3.0    1.0     17.0         31.0
B2         HTW    1.0    3.0    3.0     16.0         12.0
B3         ASD    0.0    8.0    0.0     16.0         16.0
B4         ASD    1.0   10.0    0.0     21.0         23.0
```

So I want to add and multiply columns with matching prices from `df2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `dot` for the multiplication and `join` to `df1`:

```
#set indices if needed
df1 = df1.set_index("ITEM")
df2 = df2.set_index("prices")

output = df1.join(df1.drop("tag", axis=1).dot(df2).add_suffix("_price"))

>>> output
  ITEM  tag  A35  A37  A38  day1_price  day2_price
0   B1  SAS    8    3    1          17          31
1   B2  HTW    1    3    3          16          12
2   B3  ASD    0    8    0          16          16
3   B4  KLD    1   10    0          21          23
```